# Design desktop applications

Tags: user-interface, desktop-application

I create a desktop application. Are there any books or sites on which there are examples of design desktop applications?

Comment: Are you asking how to technically solve it, or rather how to achieve a good interface design?

Comment: to achieve a good interface design

Answer (score 4):

I found [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main) as a valuable resource when it comes to UI design questions.

There are also a few platform specific "best practices": [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511440.aspx) for Windows or [this one](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/index.html) for java applications.

Comment: to achieve a good interface design

Answer (score 2):

This book contains some good Interface Design Patterns: [Designing Interfaces: Patterns for Effective Interaction Design](http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/) + [link to patterns from the 2<sup>nd</sup> edition](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/)

Also this post contains some valuable resources: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/

Comment: The first link is not working.

Comment: It has changed to http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/. Also this is a link to patterns from the second edition http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/

Comment: @M.Medhat : If your answer is not up-to-date, includes false or non-exact info or broken links, edit it. Thanks.